# Is there a nice javascript dialog box for JQuery that works with mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, mobile

Mobile browsers.
Jquery dialog alert box.

I don't want to use alert() because it looks ugly in web browsers.

I'm building a website for BOTH mobile and web, so I need a dialog box that can work on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jQuery UI [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). It uses standard HTML so it ought to look ok in both web and mobile web.  You'd have to be careful with the width/height parameters and the CSS you apply.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [jQuery Alert Dialogs](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) plugin. It provides nice-looking themeable dialog boxes for alert, confirm and prompt replacements.

Check the [Demo page](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/).